# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i want get feed from my account twitter php data json , my php already done and work , but the problem withe jquery have error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var dmJSON = "get_tweets.php";
   $.getJSON(dmJSON, function(data) {
     var html = '';
     for (var i = 0; i < data.array.length; i++) {

       html += '<div style="width: 600;direction: rtl;background-color: white;padding: 12px 12px 0;border: 1px solid;border-color: #e5e6e9 #dfe0e4 #d0d1d5;border-radius: 4px;margin-bottom: 20px;color: black;">';

       html += '<span style=""> ' + data.array[i].text + ' </span><span></span>';

       html += '</div>';
     }
     // append all the html variable to the ticker div.
     $('.tweets-container').append(html);
   });

 });
```

and i want add time for auto update json withe reload page

thanks

Comment: Can you print `data`? run `console.log(data);` before loop

Comment: check what you get using a simple `console.log(data)`

Comment: @Satpal actually am confused i need full answer

Comment: The function(data) data.array is not defined or data is empty.

Comment: @razak `data` probably doesn't contain a property called `array`, that's why they want you to show the contents of `data` (after `function (data) { ...`)

Comment: @JesperHøjer can you give me full answer please ,

Comment: @Arg0n can you give me full answer please

Comment: @AliMamedov no , there no print

Comment: @razak, see your updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/b6v9ph4s/2/ . run It, and tell what you receive in alert window

Comment: @razak No one will be able to help you if you won't show the whole picture (`data`).

Comment: @AliMamedov , thanks man

Answer (score 0):

i fixed

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var dmJSON = "get_tweets.php";
    $.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {

var html = '';

     // loop through all the news items, and append the 
     // title and published date to the html variable.

     for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

         html += '<div style="width: 600;direction: rtl;background-color: white;padding: 12px 12px 0;border: 1px solid;border-color: #e5e6e9 #dfe0e4 #d0d1d5;border-radius: 4px;margin-bottom: 20px;color: black;" class="container-fluid">';

         html += '<h4>' + data[i].text + '</h4>' ;

         html += '</div>';

      }

      // append all the html variable to the ticker div.
      $('.tweets-container').append(html);
        });

 });
```